# OpenSSL test if server supports SSLv2

Tags: security, ssl

How to do this with the openssl command:

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect localhost:443
```

I want to check for the DROW attack on non standard ports (test.drownattack.com)

Answer (score 2):

You can try the command with the option `-ssl2` if supported by your version of openssl:

```
openssl s_client -connect localhost:443 -ssl2
```

If SSLv2 is disabled you should get an error response.

Please refer to [s_client - SSL/TLS client program](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/apps/s_client.html) for the latest version.

Have a look at: [An OpenSSL User’s Guide to DROWN](https://www.openssl.org/blog/blog/2016/03/01/an-openssl-users-guide-to-drown/) for securing your system against DROWN attack.